# Subclass from instance of another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, temporary-files

I am trying to add functionality (new method) to temporary file.
Usually, the file is called by `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(*args, **kwargs)`, but `NamedTemporaryFile` is a *function*, not a *class*.
I don't want to skip this function. I want to let the function create the file but also add my method.

I tried the following (among other stuff), but my methods were not recognized:

```py
import tempfile
from tempfile import _TemporaryFileWrapper

class TempFile(_TemporaryFileWrapper):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        ret= tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(args, kwargs)
        self = cls.__init__(ret)
        return self

    def __init__(self, mode='w+b', buffering=-1, encoding=None, newline=None, suffix=None, prefix=None, dir=None):
        print('__init__')
    
    def MyMethod(self):
        print('my method works')
```

any ideas?

Comment: More about `(Named)TemporaryFile` not being a class: https://bugs.python.org/issue22387, https://bugs.python.org/issue33762

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass `tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper`, then monkey-patch the name so that `NamedTemporaryFile` returns an instance of your subclass.

```
class TempFile(tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper):
    ...

tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper = TempFile

x = NamedTemporaryFile(...)
```

This *should* work (untested), since `NamedTemporaryFile` is hard-coded to return an instance of `_TemporaryFileWrapper`, whatever that name is bound to.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you create circular reference between TempFile and tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper

Comment: No, because I'm just rebinding the name. `TempFile` subclasses whatever class `tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper` *used* to reference.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, This seems to do the trick, it just doesn't really feel right.
If some one have better idea I will happily accept their answer.

```
import tempfile
class TempFile(object):
    def __init__(self, mode='w+b', buffering=-1, encoding=None, newline=None, suffix=None, prefix=None, dir=None):
        t = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode)
        self.file = t
        # These are actually not necessary, but they make it it easier with auto-complete in the IDE.
        self.name= t.name
        self.close = t.close
        self.write = t.write

    def __get__(self):
        return self.file

    def MyMethod(self):
        print('my method works')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = TempFile(mode='w')
    t2 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w')
    print(t.name)
    print(t2.name)
    t.MyMethod()
```

Comment: What does not feel right after you remove all the unused parameters?

Comment: Usually, get should return self. Make it return something else just seems like "cheating"

Comment: Also, it feels like there will be unplanned consequences to that approach, but I'm not sure

Comment: What is the purpose of defining `__get__`? Your test code works the same without it. That aside it looks like you just discovered the [decorator pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator).

Comment: with the __get__, TempFile(mode='w') returns the file object, so I can do, for example, t.write('text') like with t2. I don't see what decorators have to do with it.

Comment: I see. I couldn't find `__get__` without parameters documented anywhere but if you know it should return `self` then I agree that you shouldn't be returning anything else. Explicit delegation (which you are already doing anyway) feels safer.